# Relation between current and used energy

Tags: batteries, dc-motor

*Thinking about a dc motor and a constant voltage battery, if you slow down the motor by resisting it physically without stopping it, its resistance increases, right? Therefore reducing the current in the circuit, since the voltage is constant.*

In a similar way, when you benchmark a computer, compared to idle, it should increase the resistance, therefore reducing current. But, I also know that using the computer uses more electricity.

*And how about the example above, does the slower spinning motor equal lower battery drain?*

I think I am totally misunderstanding things, which is why I need a little bit of redirection.

Comment: "Thinking about a dc motor and a constant voltage battery, if you slow down the motor by resisting it physically without stopping it, its resistance increases, right?" Nope. It does the opposite.

Comment: Remember: induction-based motors, when halted, act like short circuits, while capacitor-based motors (electrostatic, acrylic and metal foil,) they act like open circuits when halted.

Comment: I understand that when a motor is halted it is an entirely different story. Which is why I added "without stopping it"

Comment: @MuratErdem Ignacio is still correct.

Comment: If you stop the motor completely then its resistance decreases a lot. If you stop the motor a little bit (i.e. slow it down) then its resistance decreases a little bit.

Comment: Motors and computers are non-linear loads.  They don't follow simple ohms law.

Comment: @RDrast Not this discussion again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some comments already stated, the resistance decreases when you put a physical load on an inductive Motor.

The reason can be described by Lenz's Law ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law)). If the motor spins faster (no physical load) there will be more changes of the magnetic field (higher RPM), which results in an induction which works against the current flow of the supply voltage. That means there is less current that flows -> higher Resistance.

If you attach a physical load, that slows down the RPM of the motor, the changes of the magnetic field will be less and so the Induction reduces, which results in a lower resistance (more accurate: impedance[[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance)]).And as you know a lower resistance will result in a higher current by a constant voltage (Ohm's Law).

Answer (score 1):

> Thinking about a dc motor and a constant voltage battery, if you slow down the motor by resisting it physically without stopping it, its resistance increases, right?

Wrong.

As a motor speeds up it generates back-EMF (back-voltage due to acting as a generator) which *reduces* the current. e.g., A 12 V motor might draw 100 mA if allowed to run freely on no load but might draw 2 A if loaded to 50% speed and 4 A if stalled.

> Therefore reducing the current in the circuit, since the voltage is constant.

Current increases with increasing load.

> In a similar way, when you benchmark a computer, compared to idle, it should increase the resistance, therefore reducing current.

No. The *conductance* (the inverse of resistance) increases and the resistance decreases allowing more current to flow.

> But, I also know that using the computer uses more electricity.

Correct.

> And how about the example above, does the slower spinning motor equal lower battery drain?

As explained, the loaded motor will draw more current. The stopped motor current will be the worst case and determined by by the motor resistance and supply voltage.